# Python PostgreSQL table creation using pg_dump

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I'm trying to replicate the table structure of an existing PostgreSQL database. I have 2 databases currently, A and B. I used the "pg_dump -s" command and generated the sql query to create the tables of A. In my python script, I have the following code to create the same structure in database B:

```
con2 = psycopg2.connect(database="Archives", user="postgres", password="root", host="127.0.0.1", port="5432")

dbexe = """
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 9.6.0
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 9.6.0

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

--
-- Name: plpgsql; Type: EXTENSION; Schema: -; Owner: 
--

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plpgsql WITH SCHEMA pg_catalog;


--
-- Name: EXTENSION plpgsql; Type: COMMENT; Schema: -; Owner: 
--
several thousand more lines ...."""

cur2 = con2.cursor()
cur2.execute(dbexe)
print("done")
```

The code seems to run fine but when I check database B I don't see any tables. Any suggestions as to why this may be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must `commit` the transaction at the end because by default any data manipulation is rolled back and lost.

```
cur.commit()
```

Alternatively, you can set `autocommit` to `True` at the beginning to commit each new data automatically to the db.

```
conn.autocommit = True
```

Comment: Than you can mark this as the best answer solution ;)